# should you control for firm size as a control if you use firm fixed effects?

Tags: regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I have come across papers where the authors argue that you should not control for firm size if you use firm fixed effects. The argument is that firm fixed effects control for cross-sectional characteristics so, firm size as a control in the regression does not make sense. Study in reference Comerton-forde (2011) "Why do traders choose to trade anonymously?".
So the question is

- Should you control for firm size as a control if you already use firm fixed effects? Assuming you have panel data.

Comment: Do firms change size over time in your sample?

Comment: most firms change size as the sample ranges for 10+ years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed effects will only control for time-invariant firm characteristics. An example might be firm location or industry (though these can sometimes change too). Controlling for size may make sense if firms grow or shrink over time and you have an actual panel (rather than repeated cross-sections). For example, if the outcome of interest was the output of widgets, it would make sense to control for firm size since the output is proportional to size.

There are some situations where size might be a lousy control to include or does not make sense, but having firm FEs is insufficient to put you into this situation on its own.